# How to pass setter property as argument to a function?

Tags: python, function, properties

I am trying to pass a setter property as argument to a function.
I have following properties for my class.

```
@property
def drawMode(self):
    return self._drawMode

@drawMode.setter
def drawMode(self, value):
    self._drawMode = value
```

I can pass the getter as an argument into a function as follows:

```
rectItem = CustGraphicsRectItem(rect, self.drawMode)
```

What is the syntax for passing the setter?

Comment: What sort of object are you intending to pass to the function? How does the code you want to pass the setter to expect to interact with it? The `self.drawMode` you're using to "pass the getter" is actually passing the current value stored by the property. It's not passing a function or a property object. There's no obvious equivalent for setting a value (maybe you should just call something that returns a value that you assign to `self.drawMode` yourself).

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the property object directly and avoid magic strings. You still need to pass the instance:

```
class Class:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.__value = "old value"


    @property
    def value( self ):
        return self.__value


    @value.setter
    def value( self, value ):
        self.__value = value


def function( instance, property_ ):
    print( property_.fget( instance ) )
    property_.fset( instance, "new value" )
    print( property_.fget( instance ) )


instance = Class()
function( instance, Class.value )
```

Output:

```
old value
new value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that if you pass the property's **name** to the function (along with the object itself). This allows the property object to be retrieved from the class of the object. Once that's obtained, its `__set__()` can be called directly.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._drawMode = None

    def foobar(self):
        pass

    @property
    def drawMode(self):
        return self._drawMode

    @drawMode.setter
    def drawMode(self, value):
        self._drawMode = value


def CustGraphicsRectItem(rect, obj, prop_name):
    obj_type = type(obj)
    if prop_name not in obj_type.__dict__:
        raise TypeError('{!r} is not an attribute of class {}'.format(
                            prop_name, obj_type.__name__))
    else:
        prop = obj_type.__dict__[prop_name]
        if not isinstance(prop, property):
            raise TypeError('{!r} is not an property of class {}'.format(
                                prop_name, obj_type.__name__))

    prop.__set__(obj, 42)  # Set property's value via direct call to setter.
    return rect

test = Test()
rect = [0, 0, 10, 20]
print(test.drawMode)  # -> None
rectItem = CustGraphicsRectItem(rect, test, 'drawMode')
print(test.drawMode)  # -< 42
```